# Flag "link only" answers as "Not an answer"

Tags: discussion, flagging

How should a reviewer flag a link-only answer? Hint, the answer is in the title.

However... whilst it is obvious (to most people) which flags apply to which answers - when those answers are really just comments and those answers that are just gibberish - I've never totally and fully understood the subtle difference between **Not an answer** and **Low quality answer**, with respect to the queues and the flags that the moderators see. This following post goes some way to explaining the difference.

*This is copied verbatim from [Please don't flag link-only answers as Very Low Quality](https://meta.askubuntu.com/q/19430/348964)*

---

> Lately I notice that many link-only (or link-mainly) answers are being
> flagged as Very Low Quality, so I am taking to meta to ask y'all to
> use the Not An Answer flag for link-only answer (LOA) posts instead.
>
> I realise that the phrase "very low quality" is incredibly vague and
> open to endless interpretation, but the flag called Very Low Quality
> is only to be used for posts which are incoherent and **not
> salvageable by editing**.
>
> Now, it's true that most of [the posts we consider Not An Answer](https://askubuntu.com/help/deleted-answers),
> such as answers thanking other answers, answers that say "I have the
> same problem; have you solved it yet?" and so on, are not salvageable
> by editing.
>
> But there is one category of Not An Answer post that is fairly likely
> to be salvageable by editing, and that is link-only answers. Many new
> users, when prompted by a comment, will go ahead and expand their
> answer to include details from a link, and other users might be able
> and willing to edit such posts into shape themselves (I do it pretty
> frequently). It's not always appropriate to edit link-only answers
> (for instance, there may be copyright issues if we reproduce material
> from outside sources) but quite often it is, and editing might
> sometimes even make them good, upvoteable answers.
>
> Now, you may well be thinking at this point that I'm being pedantic.
> Who cares what the flag is called as long as the post gets the correct
> treatment, right? The reason I care a lot about this is that the Very
> Low Quality flag has a really interesting "feature", which is that any
> action, except deletion, that resolves such a flag cast on an answer
> as helpful, will automatically cast a downvote on that answer. And for
> some reason, editing a post flagged Very Low Quality resolves that
> flag as helpful (even though the flag is supposed to be raised on
> posts that are not salvageable by editing) (this includes when the
> author edits) (this isn't the case for Not An Answer flags, by the
> way). So on those not-infrequent occasions when I find an answer
> flagged Very Low Quality (link-only or not) that I want to fix by
> editing, I have to do one of these things to avoid it being
> automatically downvoted:
>
> - delete the post (resolves the flag as helpful), undelete it and edit it (if it was flaggable)
> - decline the flag, and then edit the post (if the answer wasn't flaggable at all in my opinion)
>
> I don't mind doing that, but, sometimes I forget to do it and edit
> first and the post gets downvoted. Ugh. Or someone else edits the post
> first (probably the author, poor soul), and it gets downvoted. Ugh. Or
> another mod dismisses the flag as helpful without deleting it because,
> although it's relying quite heavily on a link (or for some other
> reason was understandably flagged) it's actually not a link-only
> answer* (or otherwise deleteable), and it gets downvoted. Ugh. Nothing
> removes those downvotes!
>
> **In conclusion, please flag link-only answers as Not An Answer** (unless you can fix them yourself or the author has indicated that
> they will do so imminently).
>
> **Why is a link-only answer not an answer?** See this Meta Stack Exchange post [Your answer is in another castle: when is an answer not
> an answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer) (ironically I'm relying totally on that link...)
>
> ---
>
> ***When is a link-only answer not Not An Answer, and what is a link-only answer anyway?**
>
> A link-only answer is one that is not useful at all without the link.
> Sometimes answers that are useful without the link(s) they contain are
> flagged, but should not be. For example, an answer that gives a
> *specific, relevant recommendation*, even if it's very short, and includes a link that gives a step-by-step procedure to follow that
> recommendation, is not a link-only answer, because it's still useful
> without the link. Such answers can very often be improved, of course,
> by adding some version of the step-by-step procedure.
>
> There are very rare occasions when a link-only answer is an answer and
> should not be flagged. Sometimes, the question asks for something
> which cannot practically be included in the post. For example:
>
> > I need a driver for this thingy I have
>
> > There is a driver for your thingy `[in this repository](URL)`
>
> Well, some installation instructions would be good, but we can't put
> the driver itself in the post, so this type of answer should not
> generally be flagged or deleted (commenting or editing or downvoting
> may be appropriate though).